# ftp downloading very slow, how to reduce the number of login times?

Tags: bash, shell, ftp, download, sftp

I have great trouble in downloading my files (thousands of files) from a remote ftp server. To download a few files it is not big deal, but when there are thousands of files need to be downloaded, I found the log in operation really slows down the whole process. I need help for a better scripts.

The remote folder and files structure is something like

```
CASE
--processor0
----0
------A.gz
------B.gz
------(and so on)
------H.gz
----0.1
------A.gz
------B.gz
------(and so on)
------H.gz
----0.2
------A.gz
------B.gz
------(and so on)
------H.gz
----(And so on with 0.3 0.4 0.5 ...)
--processor1
----0
------A.gz
------B.gz
------(and so on)
------H.gz
----0.1
------A.gz
------B.gz
------(and so on)
------H.gz
----0.2
------A.gz
------B.gz
------(and so on)
------H.gz
----(And so on with 0.3 0.4 0.5 ...)
.............(and so on)
--processor2000
----0
------A.gz
------B.gz
------(and so on)
------H.gz
----0.1
------A.gz
------B.gz
------(and so on)
------H.gz
----0.2
------A.gz
------B.gz
------(and so on)
------H.gz
----(And so on with 0.3 0.4 0.5 ...)
```

So I wrote a shell script as below:

```
#!/bin/bash

stty -echo
read -p "Enter your password [ENTER]: " THISPASS; echo
stty echo
USERNAME="superman"
URL="supercomputer.org"

ROOTPATH="/home/remote/folder/CASE"
TIMELIST="0 0.1 0.2 0.3 0.4 0.5 0.6"

mkdir -p /home/LOCALFOLDER
LOCALDIR=/home/LOCALFOLDER
cd $LOCALDIR

echo ""
echo "Local Directory  : "$LOCALDIR
echo "Remote URL       : "$URL
echo "Remote Directory : "$ROOTPATH
echo ""

for TIMENAME in $TIMELIST; do
    for (( i = 0; i < 1200; i++ )); do
        CURPROC="processor"${i}
        FILEPATH=$ROOTPATH/$CURPROC
        mkdir -p $PWD/$CURPROC/$TIMENAME
        cd $PWD/$CURPROC/$TIMENAME
        echo -e "FOLDER - "$FILEPATH/$TIMENAME

        FILEFULLNAMEA=$FILEPATH/$TIMENAME/"A.gz"
        FILEFULLNAMEB=$FILEPATH/$TIMENAME/"B.gz"
        FILEFULLNAMEC=$FILEPATH/$TIMENAME/"C.gz"
        FILEFULLNAMED=$FILEPATH/$TIMENAME/"D.gz"
        FILEFULLNAMEE=$FILEPATH/$TIMENAME/"E.gz"
        FILEFULLNAMEF=$FILEPATH/$TIMENAME/"F.gz"
        FILEFULLNAMEG=$FILEPATH/$TIMENAME/"G.gz"
        FILEFULLNAMEH=$FILEPATH/$TIMENAME/"H.gz"
        lftp sftp://$USERNAME:$THISPASS@$URL -e "get $FILEFULLNAMEA $FILEFULLNAMEB $FILEFULLNAMEC $FILEFULLNAMED $FILEFULLNAMEE $FILEFULLNAMEF $    FILEFULLNAMEG $FILEFULLNAMEH; bye"
        cd ../..
    done
done
echo ""
```

But I found the `lftp sftp://$USERNAME:$THISPASS@$URL -e "get $FILEFULLNAMEA $FILEFULLNAMEB $FILEFULLNAMEC $FILEFULLNAMED $FILEFULLNAMEE $FILEFULLNAMEF $    FILEFULLNAMEG $FILEFULLNAMEH; bye"` is the most time consuming part during this downloading. Is there any better solution so that I dont need to log in all the time? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some options:

1. Use `mirror` in `lftp` to simply grab the entire directory structure that you want. It looks like the remote side has more or less the right directory structure (aside from `uniform`), so if you mirror the remote side locally, you can simply `mv` the directories locally into the right place.
2. Create all the local directories up front, then create a single script file that has all the files you want to get (interspersed with all the `lcd` commands you need to put them in the right places, and then do a single `lftp -f` of that script file. That will batch all of the gets in a single login as well.

Comment: My time directory list is increasing with my simulation, which means, now it has `{0,0.1,0.2,0.3}`, several hours later it will have `{0,0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4}`. Each time, I would only want to download a single time snapshot from all processors, so I guess `mirror` method is not what I want.

Comment: Or maybe I can create a very large scripts file by brutal force and then use `lftp -f`?

Comment: @Daniel what did you figure out? Please share!